# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on docker web application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, django-allauth

I am undergoing a web project using django and docker. The tutorial references how to set up an email service. I registered with AWS and followed a guide of how to link it to docker. The first step is to run "pip install --upgrade boto3". This is followed by the error in the title. How do I install boto3 through docker?

Comment: Do you have Python installed? Have you tried pip3 instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [docker-boto3](https://hub.docker.com/r/shinofara/docker-boto3/) docker image instead of installing and maintaining a docker image for your self.

```
docker run --rm -t \
    -v $HOME/.aws:/home/worker/.aws:ro \
    -v ${pwd}/example:/work \
    shinofara/docker-boto3 python example.py
```

or you can create your own docker image

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --update python3  \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install boto3 requests PyYAML pg8000 -U \
        && ln -sv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
```

[Boto3 Dockerfile](https://github.com/onfido/docker-py3-boto3/blob/master/Dockerfile)